# How to play MPMediaItemCollection from a particular index using MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a playlist screen in my app where users can choose any song in the playlist and the app will start playing from that song.

I use the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MPMediaItem *selectedSong = [currentQueue.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [audioCoordinator.musicController setNowPlayingItem: selectedSong];
    [audioCoordinator playAllSound];
}
```

It works well with a playlist with all distinct songs, but since this playlist allows duplicate songs, here comes the problem. For this playlist:

1. Long Long Ago
2. My December
3. Long Long Ago

When the user taps on the 3rd song, the app would play the 1st song, since they have identical names, this is not the correct behavior.

How can we provide the setNowPlayingItem function of MPMusicPlayerController an index so that it can start playing from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

in the function playAllSound:

```
while (self.musicController.indexOfNowPlayingItem != self.currentSongIndex) {
    [self.musicController skipToNextItem];
}
```

Here, self.currentSongIndex has the same value of indexPath.row, since the there's a `audioCoordinator.currentSongIndex = indexPath.row` line in the tableViewController's `didSelectCell` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is visible that selectedSong bases on indexPath.row, log indexPath.row you check for playAllSound i think it shud b play

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say, but your "log indexPath.row and check for playAllSound" inspired me and I found the solution, so thank you.

Comment: i mean to say that we are selecting the right song with reference to the cell tapped, but you are using playAllSound, which in my opinion shud b playSound which play just one song

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, playAllSound is a function that plays one song, but it's call "AllSong" because it does not only play songs, it also plays something else simultaneously.